# Why is %b deprecated in Printf?

Tags: printf, ocaml

The [Printf module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) API details the type conversion flags, among them:

```
%B: convert a boolean argument to the string true or false
%b: convert a boolean argument (deprecated; do not use in new programs).
```

But it does not say why `%b` is deprecated. Why is `%B` better than `%b`?

Comment: Because in most other languages that support printf-style formatting, `%b`, if it means anything, means print binary (a string of 0s and 1s)?

Comment: @ChrisDodd according to the documentation I've found, it does not mean anything in (standard) C or C++, stands for escaped string in bash and boolean for java. Apparently Python uses `b`, but inside a custom formatting directive such as `{x:b}` which is unlikely to be confused with `%b`. I've found a mention of `%b` for binary in Perl, but here `%B` is a quasi synonym (you end up with `0bxxxxx...` or `0Bxxxxx...`), thus I don't see a compelling reason for favoring one above the other. At least now: of course, things were possibly different when `%b` was deprecated in OCaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People would answer officialy like: conversions with capital letters like `%C` and `%S` (not `%c` and `%s`) print things in parsable formats by OCaml.  The change of `%b` to `%B` followed this, since it prints booleans as `true` and `false` which are also OCaml parsable.

You can find a backstory here: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=1438 .  There was a branch which introduced this `%B` then changed the meaning of `%b` for binaries.  The latter broke the backward compatibility therefore that part was rejected.  As the result, today we have two conversions for booleans `%B` and `%b`.